# Check to which class a property belongs in PHP

Tags: php

Okay, let's say I have a string named `test` and I know that this string is actually used as a property name in one of my classes. Is there a way to find out which class has a name with the name `test`?

Something like this maybe:

```
class Foobar {
    private $foo;
}

class Bazbar {
    private $test;
}

$attr_name = 'test';
echo get_class_name_by_attr($attr_name); // Would output Bazbar
```

Quickly improvised this code...

Is there a way to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this, aside from looping through every class and using reflection to check the properties.... and even then, new properties can be dynamically added to any instance of a class.... and several different classes can have properties of the same name

Comment: Why are you defining `$test` `private`? I don't think that will work anyway.

Comment: What Mark Baker said: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php + http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: It does raise the question of why you need this! If you don't know the properties of your classes, then you're doing something wrong

Comment: Instead of trying to answer you let me ask you a question: why do you think you need this? [Read more about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Can you describe more generally what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you need to find which class has a particular property defined? My instinct is that your approach could be revised to sidestep the problem all together.

As far as I know there is no way to test if a class has a non-static property defined, without creating an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with those people who think that you have to re-analyze your problem. But the answer of the question is something like this:

```
foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) {
    if (property_exists($class, 'test')) {
        echo $class. " has the propriety test.\n"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(I'm still asking myself why you need this, but i hope this helps)

```
<?php

    class Foobar {
        private $foo;
    }

    class Bazbar {
        private $test;
    }


    $attr_name = "test";
    $check_classes = array("Foobar", "Bazbar");

    foreach($check_classes as $k => $v) {
        $obj = new $v();
        $obj = new ReflectionClass($obj);
        $classes[]   = $obj->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED | ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);
    }

    foreach($classes as $class) {
        foreach($class as $prop) {

            if($prop->getName() == $attr_name)
                echo "Class: " . $class[0]->class. " Prop: " . $prop->getName();

        }
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
Class: Bazbar Prop: test
```

Here i added an array which search in these classes form the attr. name. For this i use Reflection. You can read up on this here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: Why don't something like `foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) { if (property_exists($class, 'test')) { echo $class. " has test prop\n"; }}`?

Comment: @Leggendario lol, didn't thought of that, you're absolutely right, you can write a answer if you want!